# Dial several numbers depending on which are in the database with twilio

Tags: php, sql, twilio

I am trying to call several numbers when a sensor submits a value.

The sensor submits a value and a sensorid. When there are several contacts in the database, it has to call all those numbers.
This code selects the triggers and which numbers it has to dial. If there are 2 numbers, it has to dial to both of them.

```php
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM alarmtriggers WHERE sensor_id = '$sensor_id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        /* Als waarde gelijk is aan */
        if ($row['type'] == 'vast') {
            if ($row['waarde'] = $val1) {

                // get the phonenumbers it needs to dial
                $sql2 = "SELECT telefoonnummer FROM alarmnummers WHERE sensor_id = '$sensor_id'";
                $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);

                if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
                    while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $phonenumber = $row2["telefoonnummer"]; // phonenumbers it needs to dial
                // execute this link several times, depending on how many contacts are in the database 
                // mirandaleus.nl/includes/alarmbot/call.php?sensorid=$sensor_id&callto=$phonenumber
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the call.php:

```php
<?php

require "vendor/autoload.php";

use Twilio\Rest\Client;

$sid    = "mysid";
$token  = "mytoken";
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

$sensor_id = $_REQUEST["sensor_id"];
$callto = $_REQUEST["callto"];
$call = $twilio->calls
    ->create(
        $callto, // to
        "+12242631292", // from
        array("url" => "https://mirandaleus.nl/includes/alarmbot/includes/cas_xml.inc.php?sensor=$sensor_id")
    );

print($call->sid);
```

call_xml.inc.php :

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/xml'); ?>
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";
$dbname = 'mydbname';

$sensor_id = $_GET['sensor'];
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = "SELECT sensor_naam FROM sensoren WHERE sensor_id = '$sensor_id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $sensornaam = $row['sensor_naam'];
    }
}
?>
<Response>
    <Say voice="alice" language="nl-NL">
        Het alarm van sensor <?php echo $sensornaam ?> gaat af.
    </Say>
    <Pause length="1" />
    <Say voice="alice" language="nl-NL">
        Het alarm van sensor <?php echo $sensornaam ?> gaat af.
    </Say>
    <Pause length="1" />
    <Say voice="alice" language="nl-NL">
        Het alarm van sensor <?php echo $sensornaam ?> gaat af.
    </Say>
    <Pause length="1" />
    <Say voice="alice" language="nl-NL">
        Einde bericht
    </Say>
</Response>
```

So in short: It has to execute a link (or the a script) with different variables, depending on how many there are in a database.

Comment: Hm, ok, nice explanation. Does anything not work? Are the wrong numbers called? Please edit your "question" and paste relevant information

Comment: Is `mirandaleus.nl` an external domain, that has nothing to do with your system? If not, then I don’t see why this should happen via additional HTTP requests in the first place, looks to me as if directly executing the relevant code from call.php multiple times within the context of the current script should do the job just fine. (Only the parts currently fishing data out of $_REQUEST would have to be changed to use local variables from the current scope directly, or you would have to populate the values into $_REQUEST via simple assignment before locally including the call.php script)

Comment: @kerbholz , everthing is working except that i want to execute that link with the amount of phonenumbers listed in the database. The amount of numbers can be changed depending on the user. If he has 5 contacts in there, 5 people will be called. If he has 3, those 3 people will be called. I'm not really sure how I'm supposed to do this.

Comment: @04FS, no it isn't. I am not really sure how to use it in a diffrent way, I know it could be something with POST but I'm not entirly sure how.

Comment: Try the following: Set `$callto` in your while loop, `$sensor_id` is already set. Make the `require "vendor/autoload.php";` in `call.php` into a `require_once` instead (otherwise that’s likely to blow up, when the script gets included multiple times), and comment out the two lines that fill `$sensor_id` and `$callto` with data from `$_REQUEST`. Then require `call.php` inside of the while loop, after you have set $callto.

Comment: @04FS Thanks, that worked for me. It is executing several calls now.

Answer (score 0):

This does not need to be done via an extra HTTP request for each call, you can directly include the call.php script inside your loop with a few, small modifications. HTTP requests add “overhead” and slow stuff down, and since the actual Twilio API call means one HTTP request for each call already, best not to add another one for each on top of that.

When the script gets included directly, it doesn’t need to fish its parameters out of $_REQUEST, but can directly access all variables in the current scope of where it gets included.

The following small modifications should to the job:

main script:

```
if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
  while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
    $callto = $row2["telefoonnummer"]; // phonenumbers it needs to dial
    require '{path-from-this-location}/call.php';
  }
}
```

call.php:

```
<?php

require_once "vendor/autoload.php"; // require_once, so that this doesn’t crash when call.php 
                                    // itself gets included multiple times in the loop

use Twilio\Rest\Client;

$sid    = "mysid";
$token  = "mytoken";
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

// commented out, these variables are in the current scope inside the while loop already,
// and therefor accessible directly here
//$sensor_id = $_REQUEST["sensor_id"];
//$callto = $_REQUEST["callto"];

// rest from here on, same as before
$call = $twilio->calls(…);
```